# Communication link failure with pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
import time
connection = pyodbc.connect(..............)
cursor = connection.cursor()
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    cursor.execute(INSERT_QUERY)
    cursor.commit()
```

that works. but suddenly I got an exception `pyodbc.Error: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Why is that ?Why the link suddenly disconnect ? How can I handle that exeption and re-connect?  how can I fix that?

Comment: Your code isn't valid Python, by the way – sort of unlikely that that's what you're running.

Comment: @YKX I have update my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By googling the error code, it means the connection failed for some reason for another.

You might want to add retry/reconnection logic for that case; crudely something like this.

```
import pyodbc
import time

connection = None
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if not connection:  # No connection yet? Connect.
        connection = pyodbc.connect("..............")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(INSERT_QUERY)
        cursor.commit()
    except pyodbc.Error as pe:
        print("Error:", pe)
        if pe.args[0] == "08S01":  # Communication error.
            # Nuke the connection and retry.
            try:
                connection.close()
            except:
                pass
            connection = None
            continue
        raise  # Re-raise any other exception
```

Comment: Is there any way to check if connection is open instead of try to execute command ?